# ActionController::MethodNotAllowed after reloading routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-routing

I have an application where I'm dynamically loading routes by a model, and calling `ActionController::Routing::Routes.reload!` after creating/updating that model. The problem is that after doing this, I'm receiving the following error when I try to hit that new route:

```
ActionController::MethodNotAllowed
Only get, head, post, put, and delete requests are allowed.
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.1.0/lib/action_controller/routing/recognition_optimisation.rb:65:in `recognize_path'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.1.0/lib/action_controller/routing/route_set.rb:384:in `recognize'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.1.0/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:148:in `handle_request'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.1.0/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:107:in `dispatch'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.1.0/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:104:in `synchronize'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.1.0/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:104:in `dispatch'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.1.0/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:120:in `dispatch_cgi'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.1.0/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:35:in `dispatch'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel/rails.rb:76:in `process'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel/rails.rb:74:in `synchronize'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel/rails.rb:74:in `process'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:159:in `process_client'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:158:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:158:in `process_client'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `initialize'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `new'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:268:in `initialize'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:268:in `new'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:268:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel/configurator.rb:282:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel/configurator.rb:281:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel/configurator.rb:281:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/mongrel_rails:128:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel/command.rb:212:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/mongrel_rails:281
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:502:in `load'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:502:in `load'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:354:in `new_constants_in'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:502:in `load'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.1.0/lib/commands/servers/mongrel.rb:64
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:27:in `gem_original_require'
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:27:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:509:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:354:in `new_constants_in'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:509:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.1.0/lib/commands/server.rb:39
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:27:in `gem_original_require'
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:27:in `require'
script/server:3
```

What's really odd is that the request has no parameters, and the response headers are `{"cookie"=>[],
 "Allow"=>"GET,
 HEAD,
 POST,
 PUT,
 DELETE",
 "Cache-Control"=>"no-cache"}`

All this even though the request is definitely GET (according to Firebug) and according to the response GET is certainly allowed.

I'm using Rails 2.1.0 and Mongrel 1.1.5 (after googling, I noticed some have problems with older versions).

Anyone have thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this was a bug in Rails 2.1.0. Upgrading to Rails 2.2.1 fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading to 2.1.2 also fixes this in case you don't want to potentially break your site with 2.2.